# Using Controlled Embedded Browser in SWT

Tags: java, browser, web, interaction

Does anyone know how to use the "Controlled Embedded Browser" in SWT, which allows page manipulation? I can only find info on how to use the normal SWT browser, but I need to be able to interact with the loaded page. Thank you. Like this -
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/btt/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.btt.application_presentation.doc_7.0%2Fdoc%2Freference%2Frichclient%2Fcontrolembededbrowser.html - but there is no instruction on how to initiate such a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet307.java) from [Eclipse SWT snippets website](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/)

Also this post might give you some insight on this.
[Using Java Objects in JavaScript in Eclipse SWT Browser Control](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/using-java-objects-in-javascript-in-eclipse-swt-browser-control/)

> To expose Java Object from Eclipse to JavaScript, you need to create a class that extends BrowserFunction. The constructor of this class takes two arguments; the first one is Browser instance and second one is name of the the function that will be available in JavaScript code running the SWT browser control... ...

**Code snippet**

BrowserFunction: 
`import java.io.File;`

import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.BrowserFunction;

public class ListFilesFunction extends BrowserFunction {

```
Browser browser = null;
String functionName = null;

public ListFilesFunction(Browser browser, String name) {
    super(browser, name);
    this.browser = browser;
    this.functionName = name;
}

public Object function (Object[] args)
{
    if (args.length == 0)
        browser.execute("alert('Function " + 
        functionName + " requires one argument - parent folder path');");

    File file = new File(args[0].toString());

    if (!file.exists())
        browser.execute("alert('Folder " + args[0] +
```

" does not exist');");

```
    if (!file.isDirectory())
        browser.execute("alert('Path " + args[0] + " must be a folder');");

    return file.list();
}
```

}

associate this function with the browser control

`public class View extends ViewPart
{
    Browser browserCtl = null;
    ...`

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    ...
    browserCtl = new Browser(parent, SWT.None);

    new ListFilesFunction(browserCtl, "getFiles");
    ...
}
...
```

}
invoke this function from JavaScript:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            files = getFiles("c:/");

        for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            document.writeln(files[i] + "<br>");
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's ok, my answer is late too :), but hope this can be reference for others